# How to change data in data layer before sending to Google Analytics?

Tags: html, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-datalayer

I tried to change some values in the data layer before it reach my Google analytics account.

I used a custom HTML tag to manipulate the data Layer. Say I wanted to multiply my room count variable by 3,

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
(function() {
  var var7 = ({{DL_roomcount}})
  
  var7 = 3*var7
  dataLayer.push({
    'roomcount' : var7
  });
    
})(); 
</script>
```

Apparently, even though it shows the new values in the data Layer in preview mode, the new values never reached the analytics account.

The trigger type I used was - custom event & event name was 'gtm.load'. In preview mode datalayer shows roomcount as 3 but in analytics account its still 1.

My GA-debug console also shows 1 instead of 3.

Any help regarding this would be highly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should push an event into the dataLayer at the same time that you are pushing the new value for `roomcount` so that you can access that new value:

```
// your other code
dataLayer.push({
   'event': 'update roomcount',
   'roomcount': var7
})
```

You can now access the new `roomcount` value if you trigger your tag to fire on the `update roomcount` event.

Comment: Thank you Nyuen for the input, I changed the code as follows,
<script type="text/javascript">

(function() {

  var var1 = ({{DL_roomcount}})

  var1 = 3*var1

  dataLayer.push({

    'event': 'update roomcount',

    'roomcount': var1
  });
    
})(); 
</script> 
but the result is same,

Comment: Post screenshots of your tag and your trigger. Also check in GTM debug mode the values in the dataLayer when the event is `update roomcount`.

Comment: Dear @nyuen, in GTM preview mode DataLayer shows 3 but tag assistant extension still shows 1 and below that I could find our update roomcount, looks like that event occurs after the data was sent.
here are some screenshots   [link](http://chocolatehusky.blogspot.com/2016/06/my-tag-and-trigger-to-edit-data-layer.html)

Comment: Whichever tag you use that makes use of the updated value should fire on the `update roomcount` event, where the new `roomcount` val should be updated.

Comment: Datalayer gets updated but the older value is being sent to the analytics account instead of new one, thank you nyuen for the input @nyuen :)

Comment: What type of tag are you using that utilises this updated dataLayer value?

Comment: Hmm.. ok, so your custom HTML tag updates the value, but where are you using that value? Do you have an event tag, or a pageview tag?

Comment: There is a pageview tag, but the value is in above custom html tag which fires at 'gtm.load'. You could see the screenshot click above link. I guess it's too late to push with html tag. ? ?Thanks @nyuen

Comment: Yes, definitely if it's on the pageview tag, then it's too late. What is happening is that your trigger fires on gtm.load, and by then the page has already loaded (at gtm.js). You should create an event tag that fires on the event I suggested.

Comment: I tried nyuen, I used gtm.js gtm.load And dom as well. It did not work same result

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at when it is that those values are read; let me give you an example.

- You click on the page.
- This causes a data layer push.
- That push causes a google analytics to fire off an event.
- You use your custom tag to edit the data layer variable.

In this situation, it's too late. You've already missed the point at which Google Analytics recieves the information.

I recommend either editing the data layer push, the data layer variable, or the tag that sends the information to Google Analytics. Adding in a 4th party just makes it more complicated.

Comment: True, thanks J,well is that pageview tag normally sends data to analytics?

Comment: @cool_kid That depends. In this situation I'd assume it was an event tag, deployed with Google Tag Manager.

Comment: Thanks J thank you very much, I'll try and will give an update